# Differences in SQL Queries Calculating Percentage Based on Gender

Tags: sql, mysql

In the below table i need to calculate the percentage of male and female employees based on their gender in a table named employee. However, I've noticed that these queries are producing different results, and i am curious to know why and how?.

```
+-------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
| EmpID | EmpName | Gender | Salary | city     |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|     1 | Arjun   | M      |  75000 | Pune     |
|     2 | Ekdanta | M      | 125000 | Banglore |
|     3 | Lalita  | F      | 150000 | Mathura  |
|     4 | Madhav  | M      | 250000 | Delhi    |
|     5 | Visakha | F      | 120000 | Mathura  |
+-------+---------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = 'M') * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS MalePercentage,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = 'F') * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS FemalePercentage;
FROM employee;
```

and another one is :

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = 'M') * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS MalePercentage,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee WHERE gender = 'F') * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS FemalePercentage ;
```

if i remove `from Employee` then why it is giving different data and how?

Comment: Because `SELECT COUNT(*)` without `FROM` clause returns 1, at least in PostgreSQL and MySQL. Your second query is logically incorrect.

Comment: working with MySQL.

Comment: It is the [same](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i6YJ5RBE2fkLVyqofWvEM6/0)

Comment: But both the queries giving different output.

Comment: Of course, COUNT(*) returns the number of rows in the first one and 1 in the second.

Comment: yes got it, thanks.

Comment: In MySQL you may use simple `SELECT AVG(gender = 'M') * 100, AVG(gender = 'F') * 100 FROM employee;`

Comment: Do you want to calculate the percentages without repeating them for each row, is that the end goal?